# MySQL Queries for v1.7 to v1.9 upgrade process

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, database, upgrade

I'm tasked with upgrading our Magento installation from v1.7 to v1.9, using [this article](https://magenticians.com/upgrade-magento-1-7-to-1-9/) as a guide. The upgrade works fine, but its not very compatible with our development and deployment process.

Any updates are done in the development environment, then deployed to staging, and once they're tested and validated, it gets deployed to production. Our deployment process is pretty straight forward, its basically just a matter of checking out the Git branch with the new code. And there aren't too many database changes that get done, so if there are, then that just consists of manually running the MySQL queries either before or after the branch is checked out.

This is where the upgrade process for Magento somewhat clashes with our deployment process. Without knowing exactly what MySQL queries the upgrade/install process runs (if any), we basically have to follow the entire upgrade process, and once its done, just overwrite all the files with whats in our git repo.

It would be much easier if I could just run any queries that magento executes myself. Is there a way to find out what queries Magento would execute? If not, can someone provide the queries for the 1.7 -> 1.9 upgrade?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it is not necessary to run SQL-queries manually ...

Last year i had to upgrade our shop from pretty old 1.5.1.0 to 1.9.x. We have +70 extensions installed and had a lot of custom DB changes. It was enough to (temporarily) remove all extension, remove all Magento files (except media folder), upload (or GIT clone) lates Magento realease and let the update scripts run. It just took some time and i had to restart upgrade process once. After that i just had to reinstall all extensions/templates (via composer/modman), adjusted local.xml and migration was done.

Comment: If the environment is simple enough, then absolutely. But if you're in a standardized environment where deployments are done programmatically, then following the installation steps for every environment is a little counterintuitive, that process cant be automated or standardized. Are the changes made to the database **all** MySQL queries? Or do you know if some DB updates are offloaded onto PHP?